# How do you compute vertical transformations in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, ellipsoid, geoid, vertical-transformation

How do you compute vertical transformations in QGIS?

Ideally, the procedure / plugin will allow the loading of sundry geoid models.